# Firebase Auth signIn distinction

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

On my website, I have two portals for login. Portal A is login for learners. Portal B is login for teachers.

Both learners' and teachers' accounts are located in the same Firebase project, in another words, both types of accounts are located in the same authentication space. Both portals use the same simple login code:
`firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(user_email, user_password).catch(function(error) {})`

Currently, the learners can login at both portals, and same for the teachers. What I am trying to do is to prevent the teachers to login at the learners' portal and vice versa. I am not sure how to implement this. I have made a `setCustomUserClaim` to give an identity to the two types of accounts on the authentication token. But I can only grab the auth token once the user is logged in, not before I think. Also, I have a Firestore collection that stores all the info of the users including their identity. But each user's document is named with their corresponding UID. The latter can be grabbed once they login in as well. Any idea on how to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Authentication has no built-in way to distinguish between these two types of users. It simply authenticates the credentials that a user enters, and ensure that they're correct. If certain users can only access a certain application or certain data, this is information that will have to come from you.

The above is important to realize, so I'll repeat it: Firebase Authentication allows all users to authenticate as long as they provide the right credentials. It has no way to block access to authentication based on application-specific information, such as your user-type. This type of *authorization* logic is part of your application, both in code and (if you use a Firebase Database) of your server-side security rules.

A common way to implement your scenario is to add the information about the types of users to a database (such as Firebase's Realtime Database, or Cloud Firestore). In this data you could for example store the email addresses of all teachers.

Now with this information, your code can then determine whether the person who signed in to the site is a teacher or not. If they're a teacher signing in to the student web site, you can redirect them, and vice versa.